# Facebook reloaded twice in web browser from mobile app

Tags: java, android, facebook, browser

---

While Clicking on facebook button,redirect to web browser and open facebook login page.After enter our credentials and need to click the CONTINUE Button, On first click of Continue button, facebook page reloaded and second time it fetched all User details (Email,first Name,Last Name,Profile pic) on Android 9 OS only..Android 10,11 12 OS devices working.

We have used android:launchmode as SINGLETASK for android 10,11 & 12.but Android 9 OS not supporting.

Library :     implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:14.1.1'
Android Manifest:

```
<provider
   android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
   android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider399122648326004"
   android:exported="true"
   tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider" /> 
<meta-data
   android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
   android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
<meta-data
   android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
   android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />
   android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
   tools:replace="android:theme" />
```

In Android code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ThemeUtils.changeTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(ApprovalInHours.this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
 facebookLogin();
});
```

Here We have written code for loginbutton and asking ReadPermissions

```
 loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(ApprovalInHours.this, Arrays.asList(
                        "email",
                        "public_profile",
                        "user_birthday"));

            }
        });
```

Code for facebookLogin() and fetching user facebook details:

```
private void facebookLogin() {
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
 Log.d("onSuccess",""+loginResult.toString());
 //Use GraphApi to get the information into the app.
    
  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  //pass two parameter
   loginResult.getAccessToken(),                       //one is the current token
   new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()            //2nd is grahJSONObject callback
 {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
  Log.v("MainActivity", response.toString() + "getToken" + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());    
// Application code
   try {
  String obj = object.toString();                     //get complete JSON object refrence.
  String name = object.getString("first_name");                 //get particular JSON Object
  String last_name = object.getString("last_name");
  final_name = name + last_name;
  Log.d("checkFinalName", "" + final_name);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  });
                                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
                                parameters.putString(
                                        "fields",
                                        "id, first_name, last_name, name, picture, email,gender"
                                );
                                request.setParameters(parameters);
                                request.executeAsync();
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            Log.d("onCancel","onCancel");
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            Log.d("onError","onCancel"+exception.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
    
        }
    
          @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if(resultCode == -1){
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                }
                Log.d("checkLog",""+"checkLog");
            }
```

Comment: Welcome. The code should be properly formatted. There's such a thing as Java Code Conventions (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Comment: Maybe someone is fine about that, but I have trouble reading code with disordered indents.